# How to check whether message is the same as sent by the publisher?

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to check whether data send by the publisher is the same as received by the subscriber. So is this check already done by the ROS or i have to use CRC , checksum like methods within the messages to ensure that data is correct .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199567/how-to-check-whether-message-is-the-same-as-sent-by-the-publisher?/) by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-12-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your publisher and subscriber are using TCPROS as the transport, then I'd say payload integrity is taken care of by the checksumming and retransmits inherent to TCP itself.

As to UDPROS, it uses UDP (..), which does have checksumming, but no reliability mechanisms (retransmitting corrupted datagrams fi). The checksum is also optional.

For any other transports (`rosserial` comes to mind), you'll have to investigate the included recovery mechanisms yourself (for `rosserial`, see [rosserial/Overview/Protocol - Packet Format](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Protocol#Packet_Format), which indicates there is a checksum included).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on 2014-12-16**:
Thanks.I have to send the messages from raspberrypi to arduino through rosserial . How to access the checksum value from the packet. According to the link u have given above,does size of a packet of N byte message data is N+8 bytes

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-16**:
I don't know the details, but according to the screenshots in [ROS Arduino message type restrictions?](http://answers.ros.org/question/199490/ros-arduino-message-type-restrictions/) fi, `rosserial` already checks for corruptions. I think it then drops those packets.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to what @gvdhoorn already stated I'd like to mention that if using TCPROS you can safely assume that messages received are transmitted correctly, unique (meaning for a single publish() the subscriber callback won't be called twice) and that for a single publisher/single subscriber connection you can safely assume that you will receive them in the same order as published; its stated here: http://answers.ros.org/question/46713/order-of-publishedsubscribed-messages/  ....; Note that message loss (due to limited bandwidth or long running subscriber callbacks) is still possible.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-16**:
@Wolf: true, I'd forgotten to mention the application layer.